# Прочитать большой pickle без MemoryError

Tags: python, pickle

Есть `test.pickle` на 1 гиг, при `pickle.load(test_file)` получаю `MemoryError`. Оперативы хватает сполна. Можно ли как-то прочитать `test.pickle` и пересохранить с новым протоколом попробовать? Он был сохранён с 4, хочу с 5 попробовать. `joblib.load` не помог. Любые хаки со сторонними библиотеками или вызовом `gc` подойдут, не хочу данные терять.

Comment: `"Оперативы хватает сполна"` - если бы хватало вы бы не получали `MemoryError`. Что у вас в pickle файле и как вы его сохраняли?

Comment: @MaxU стандартные словари словарей, сохранял дампом с 4 протоколом. Что поделать если пикл без предупреждений сохраняет такие вещи, которые потом не может сам прочитать

Answer (score 3):

Проблема была в том, что использовал Win32 инсталляцию питона на винде (на это натолкнуло то, что процесс использовал только 4 с лишним гига и вылетала ошибка). Поставил Win64 и он смог заиспользовать больше: 7.4 гига в пике для файла 1.6 гиг -- seems good!

Если надо сделать несколько load-ов подряд, то это также помогает после каждого лода:

```
data.clear()
gc.collect()
```

Отличий между 4 и 5 протоколами ни в лоаде, ни в дампе по памяти не заметил.